encounter with error after running chef-client -zr "recipe[my_cookbook::recipe2]"
[2024-04-13T05:50:25+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.
Starting Chef Infra Client, version 15.0.300
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["my_cookbook::test-recipe"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:

my_cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: my_cookbook::test-recipe


file[/myfile] action create (up to date)

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Infra Client finished, 0/1 resources updated in 01 seconds
[root@ip-10-0-2-165 cookbooks]# chef-client -zr "recipe[my_cookbook::recipe2]"
[2024-04-13T05:50:55+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.
Starting Chef Infra Client, version 15.0.300
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["my_cookbook::recipe2"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:

my_cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 2 resources
Recipe: my_cookbook::recipe2


dnf_package[tree] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action install on resource 'dnf_package[tree]'
RuntimeError
dnf-helper.py had stderr output:
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'amazonlinux':

Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for https://al2023-repos-$awsregion-de612dc2.s3.dualstack.$awsregion.$awsdomain/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240401/x86_64/mirror.list [URL rejected: Bad hostname]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 573, in load
ret = self._repo.load()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 324, in load
return _repo.Repo_load(self)
libdnf._error.Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'amazonlinux': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for https://al2023-repos-$awsregion-de612dc2.s3.dualstack.$awsregion.$awsdomain/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240401/x86_64/mirror.list [URL rejected: Bad hostname]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/provider/package/dnf/dnf_helper.py", line 92, in 
query(command)
File "/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/provider/package/dnf/dnf_helper.py", line 38, in query
sack = get_sack()
File "/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/provider/package/dnf/dnf_helper.py", line 18, in get_sack
base.fill_sack()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 406, in fill_sack
self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 141, in _add_repo_to_sack
repo.load()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 580, in load
raise dnf.exceptions.RepoError(str(e))
dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'amazonlinux': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for https://al2023-repos-$awsregion-de612dc2.s3.dualstack.$awsregion.$awsdomain/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240401/x86_64/mirror.list [URL rejected: Bad hostname]
Resource Declaration:
In /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/recipe2.rb
7: package 'tree' do
8: action :install
9: end
10:
Compiled Resource:
Declared in /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/recipe2.rb:7:in `from_file'
dnf_package("tree") do
package_name "tree"
action [:install]
default_guard_interpreter :default
declared_type :package
cookbook_name "my_cookbook"
recipe_name "recipe2"
end
System Info:
chef_version=15.0.300
platform=amazon
platform_version=2023
ruby=ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef-workstation/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2024-04-13T05:50:58+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2024-04-13T05:50:58+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 03 seconds
[2024-04-13T05:50:58+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2024-04-13T05:50:58+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2024-04-13T05:50:58+00:00] FATAL: RuntimeError: dnf_package[tree] (my_cookbook::recipe2 line 7) had an error: RuntimeError: dnf-helper.py had stderr output:
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'amazonlinux':

Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for https://al2023-repos-$awsregion-de612dc2.s3.dualstack.$awsregion.$awsdomain/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240401/x86_64/mirror.list [URL rejected: Bad hostname]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 573, in load
ret = self._repo.load()
File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/repo.py", line 324, in load
return _repo.Repo_load(self)
libdnf._error.Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'amazonlinux': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for https://al2023-repos-$awsregion-de612dc2.s3.dualstack.$awsregion.$awsdomain/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240401/x86_64/mirror.list [URL rejected: Bad hostname]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/provider/package/dnf/dnf_helper.py", line 92, in 
query(command)
File "/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/provider/package/dnf/dnf_helper.py", line 38, in query
sack = get_sack()
File "/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/chef-15.0.300/lib/chef/provider/package/dnf/dnf_helper.py", line 18, in get_sack
base.fill_sack()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 406, in fill_sack
self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 141, in _add_repo_to_sack
repo.load()
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 580, in load
raise dnf.exceptions.RepoError(str(e))
dnf.exceptions.RepoError: Failed to download metadata for repo 'amazonlinux': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (3): URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL for https://al2023-repos-$awsregion-de612dc2.s3.dualstack.$awsregion.$awsdomain/core/mirrors/2023.4.20240401/x86_64/mirror.list [URL rejected: Bad hostname]

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
